# Bugzilla - Webserver is not executing CGI files and multiply directory in apache config

Tags: apache, bugzilla

I have a little trouble for install Bugzilla. I have follow this install guide :
https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/quick-start.html

But when I test the server, I have this problem :

```
TEST-FAILED Webserver is not executing CGI files.
```

I have a multiple Directory apache configuration to handle bugzilla git and a Web application (previa3). Git and the web application work correctly.

Here my configuration file :

```
ServerName 10.5.5.83

ServerAdmin support@phoenix-isi.fr
DocumentRoot /opt/git/

Alias /previa3 /opt/previa3

Alias /bugzilla /var/www/html/bugzilla

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/previa3>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/git>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private Git Access Directory"
    AuthUserFile /opt/git/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

SuexecUserGroup git git
ScriptAlias /git /var/www/sbin/git-http-backend-wrapper
```

When I run the command

```
apache2ctl -M | grep cgi
```

The module cgi_module (shared) and cgid_module (shared) are printed.

I'm pretty sure the solution is very dumb but I can't find it. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I finally find my mistake. In apache's error log I have seen this error :

```
AH01215: suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

And in suexec log :

```
uid: (1001/git) gid: (1001/git) cmd: testagent.cgi
cannot open current working directory
```

I had some privilege issue with my bugzilla directory. I have set the owner to git.git (because I have SuexecUserGroup git git in apache config) and 755 access and now it's working like a charm.